# JavaScript Hexadecimal string to IEEE-754 Floating Point

Tags: javascript, parsing, floating-point, hex, ieee-754

I've looked around Stackoverflow for a few days trying to solve this problem and played in JsFiddle for a while but no luck so far.

Here's my problem: i receive a base64 encoded string which is packed with several values. Both Unsigned Integers and floating point numbers. The decoding of the base64 to a hex string goes fine. So do the unsigned integers. The problem lies in decoding the floats.

`b76a40e9000000350a3d422d00000059e37c409a0000002f90003b6e00000000`

This is my data, as an example well use the first 32 bits, is a IEE-754 float with byte order `1-0-3-2`.
So that's `0xb76a40e9` which i know is `7.30363941192626953125` and when we swap it to be `3-2-0-1` it becomes `0x40e9b76a`. When i put this hex string into https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html that is confirmed.

My question is, and iv'e searched for this very long, if there is an implementation in javascript that converts hexadecimal IEEE-754 float strings into a javascript float. JS' own parseInt will accept hex, but parseFloat doesn't for some reason?

Any imput would be greatly appreciated, all the examples of code people made thusfar result in different numbers than i'm expecting.

Comment: Could you explain me what is `byte order`?

Comment: @Carr this image should explain https://imgur.com/gf3pBwql.png 
It's mainly a way for the device that i receive this data from to send it over a bus. Maybe not very relevant for the question.

Comment: And `0xb76a40e9 which i know is 7.303 ` ? Under my test by `0xb76a40e9.toString(10)` the output is `3077193961` in decimal, how you get `7.303`?

Comment: @Carr you would have to swap byte order first, so `0x40e9b76a.toString(10)` should result in something like `7.30363941192626953125`

Comment: Rounding off to 7.303 makes this question unclear: Do you actually mean 7.3036394119262695?

Comment: @JoshLee Yes! You are right, I'll edit that in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unpacking a float from a word using [`DataView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView):

```
> v = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(4))
> v.setUint32(0, 0x40e9b76a)
> v.getFloat32(0)
7.3036394119262695
```

(Recommended over `Uint32Array` and `Float32Array` because it does not inherit the platform's endianness.)

You could also use this to swap the two 16-bit units:

```
> v.setUint32(0, 0xb76a40e9)
> ((hi, lo) => {
    v.setUint16(0, hi);
    v.setUint16(2, lo);
  })(v.getUint16(2), v.getUint16(0))
> v.getUint32(0).toString(16)
'40e9b76a'
```

Comment: This does pretty much exactly what i need it to do. Thanks for the quick reply!
I want to add though that since my question involves a string, it would be `v.setUint32(0, "0x40e9b76a")` in your answer. 
I'm glad that there is a built-in function that does this as opposed to having some self-fabricated function.