# convert hex to float32_LE

Tags: javascript, hex, endianness

I hope you and your family are well.
I am getting difficulty in convert hex to float32_LE. I tried some different online JavaScript editors but not working well.
If someone has an idea how can find the best resources to convert hex to float32_LE. I appreciate then in advance.
I have hex value = 0xcf91873b. It should be 0.004137255. I have found direct conversation but I need some background stuff. so I can use it in code.

Thank you
kind regards.

Comment: "I have found direct conversation but I need some background stuff." What do you mean by that? What code have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ 
here is the website. It provides conversation to float-little endian. but it shows the direct output. I want to know the function. how does it work!! :)

Comment: Okay, so what about "I tried some different online JavaScript editors but not working well." - that suggests you *have* tried some code, but run into problems. You're more likely to get help if you show what you've tried rather than just saying "I've got nothing, give me the code."

Comment: Hi Jon, here the link(https://onecompiler.com/javascript/3x7cx9khw) where can we get a float. but it seems does not work. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DataView.prototype.getFloat32()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DataView/getFloat32) method allows you to take an unsigned integer and return the floating-point representation. The first parameter is the `byteOffset`; this should be `0`. The method also takes a `littleEndian` parameter; we want to set this to `true`.

The final unpacked float 32 value is `0.004137254785746336`

**Edit:** I added the ability to decode multiple hex values.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/49221327/1762224
const parseFloat = (hex, littleEndian) => {
  const
    octets = Math.floor(hex.replace(/^0x/, '').length / 2),
    dataView = new DataView(new ArrayBuffer(octets));
  dataView.setUint32(0, parseInt(hex, 16));
  return dataView.getFloat32(0, littleEndian);
}

const ui = {
  input: document.querySelector('#input'),
  output: document.querySelector('#output'),
  convert: document.querySelector('#convert')
};

const handleConvert = (e) => {
  ui.output.value = ui.input.value.trim().split(/\s+/).map(hex =>
    parseFloat(hex, true)).join(' ');
};

ui.convert.addEventListener('click', handleConvert);
```

```css
body,html{width:100%;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;background:#000;color:#0f0}
body{display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;align-items:center}
textarea{flex:1;margin:.5em;width:calc(100% - 2em);font-family:monospace;border:thin solid #0f0;background:#000;color:#0f0;resize:none}
button{margin:0;background:#000;color:#0f0;border:thin solid #0f0;padding:.5em}
button:hover{background:#0f0;color:#000;cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<textarea id="input">0xcf91873b 0xcf91873b</textarea>
<button id="convert">Convert</button>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```